# Insert <div> outside every three <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have something like this:

```
function cat_filter() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'json/cat_filter.aspx',
        data: "catId=" + "&styleId=" + "&colourId=" + "&sizeId=" + "&minPrice=" + "&maxPrice=",
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            //load loading cursor
        }, success: function (data) {
            var CatItems = "";

            for (var x = 0; x < data.PRODUCTS.length; x++) {
                CatItems += '<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-' + [x] + ' jcarousel-item-' + [x] + '-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal"><a class="large_image" href="#"><img  src="' + data.PRODUCTS[x].product_img + '" alt="' + data.PRODUCTS[x].product_name + '"></a><h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">' + data.PRODUCTS[x].product_name + '</h3>';

                if (data.PRODUCTS[x].product_onsale == 1) {
                    CatItems += '<img alt="sale" src="assets/images/sale.gif" class="sale"><span class="geo_17_red_linethr">&pound;' + data.PRODUCTS[x].product_retailprice + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;' + data.PRODUCTS[x].product_webprice + '</span>';
                } else {
                    CatItems += '<span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;' + data.PRODUCTS[x].product_webprice + '</span>';
                }

                if (data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS) {
                    CatItems += '<span class="colour">';

                    for (var y = 0; y < data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS.length; y++) {

                        CatItems += '<span><a href="' + data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS[y].colours_large + '"><img src="' + data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS[y].colours_thumb + '" alt="' + data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS[y].colour_name + '" /></a></span>';
                    }

                    CatItems += '</span>';
                }

                CatItems += '</li>';

            }
            $('.carousel_00 ul').html(CatItems);
        }, complete: function () {
            //remove loading cursor
        }
    });
}
```

This code generates this html:

```
    <div class="carousel_00">
        <ul>            
            <li><a href="#" class="large_image"><img  src="assets/images/dress1.gif" alt="image"></a>
            <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Rachel Dress</h3>
            <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;89.99</span>
            <span class="colour">
                <span><a href="assets/images/big_image_1.gif"><img src="assets/images/black.gif" alt="balck"></a></span>
                <span><img src="assets/images/brown.gif" alt="brown"></span>
                <span><img src="assets/images/purple.gif" alt="purple"></span>
            </span>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img  src="assets/images/dress2.gif" alt="image"></a>
            <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Rachel Dress</h3>
            <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;89.99</span>
            </li>
            <li><img class="sale" src="assets/images/sale.gif" alt="sale" /><a href="#"><img  src="assets/images/dress3.gif" alt="image"></a>
            <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Rachel Dress</h3>
            <span class="geo_17_red_linethr">&pound;99.99</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;89.99</span>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img  src="assets/images/dress1.gif" alt="image"></a>
            <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Rachel Dress</h3>
            <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;59.99</span>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img  src="assets/images/dress2.gif" alt="image"></a>
            <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Rachel Dress</h3>
            <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;89.99</span>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img  src="assets/images/dress3.gif" alt="image"></a>
            <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Rachel Dress</h3>
            <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;89.99</span>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img  src="assets/images/dress1.gif" alt="image"></a>
            <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Rachel Dress</h3>
            <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;89.99</span>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img  src="assets/images/dress2.gif" alt="image"></a>
            <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Rachel Dress</h3>
            <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;89.99</span>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><img  src="assets/images/dress3.gif" alt="image"></a>
            <h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">Rachel Dress</h3>
            <span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;89.99</span>
            </li>
        </ul></div>
```

What I need is that every 3 li's will be in div /div. **I know that this is not semantic and not right, but this is only for example. (Basically if I will figure out how to do this, I will replace li's on spans and that div that i need outside li's on li).**

Will be very glad if someone will help me. Because code that I have is already too much for me.

Comment: You cannot have an li as a child element of a div, if you tell browsers to do something impossible then some will do it, and some will try to figure out what you really meant. It then becomes a nightmare to figure out what is going on. **Don't try this**. Go direct to generating valid documents.

Comment: If you didn't read my post to the end, I will just repeat last part here.

I know that this is not semantic and not right, but this is only for example. (Basically if I will figure out how to do this, I will replace li's on spans and that div that i need outside li's on li).

This is not production code, I will rewrite it if I will find a solution.

Comment: It is not 'just' semantics- insert an empty li, append a ul to that, and append the first 3 lis to the new ul.
Repeat until you are out of lis.

The browser will rewrite the code to keep lis in uls otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this first in the loop:

```
if (x % 3 === 0) CatItems += '<div>';
```

and this last in the loop:

```
if (x % 3 === 2 || x = data.PRODUCTS.length - 1) CatItems += '</div>';
```

This will group the `li` items three and tree. If you only want the `div` around the first `li` in each group, the second condition would instead be the same as the first.

(And let me repeat what you said in the question about this not being semantically correct.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using string i would use dom functions (document.createElement and element.appendChild). But if I stick with your method, it would be like this:

```
               success: function(data) {
                   var CatItems = "";

                   for(var x=0; x < data.PRODUCTS.length; x++) {
                        if(x%3==0)
                            CatItems += "<div>";
                        CatItems += '<li class="jcarousel-item jcarousel-item-horizontal jcarousel-item-'+[x]+' jcarousel-item-'+[x]+'-horizontal jcarousel-item-placeholder jcarousel-item-placeholder-horizontal"><a class="large_image" href="#"><img  src="'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_img +'" alt="' + data.PRODUCTS[x].product_name +'"></a><h3 class="geo_17_darkbrown">' + data.PRODUCTS[x].product_name +'</h3>';

                        if ( data.PRODUCTS[x].product_onsale==1 ) {
                            CatItems += '<img alt="sale" src="assets/images/sale.gif" class="sale"><span class="geo_17_red_linethr">&pound;'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_retailprice +'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_webprice +'</span>';
                        } else {
                            CatItems += '<span class="price geo_17_darkbrown">&pound;'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_webprice +'</span>';
                        }

                        if ( data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS ) {
                            CatItems += '<span class="colour">';

                            for(var y=0; y < data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS.length; y++) {

                                CatItems += '<span><a href="'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS[y].colours_large +'"><img src="'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS[y].colours_thumb +'" alt="'+ data.PRODUCTS[x].product_COLOURS[y].colour_name +'" /></a></span>';
                            }

                            CatItems += '</span>';
                        }

                        CatItems += '</li>';

                        if(x%3==0)
                            CatItems += "</div>";

                   }
                   $('.carousel_00 ul').html(CatItems);
               },
```

Comment: % - This is the modulus operator. It will return the whole number remainder if you were to divide the two numbers.

Comment: @Robert yes and if it is equals to 0 this because you have passed 3 li